# Show rich responses in web based Dialogflow agent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I tried to use Rich responses to show buttons, cards as responses from the webhook with dynamic content.

```
agent.add(new Card({
                        title: <RICH UI>,
                        imageUrl: '<IMAGE URL>',
                        text: '<CARD TEXT>',
                        buttonText: '<BUTTON>',
                        buttonUrl: '<BUTTON URL>'
                        })
                    );
agent.add(new Suggestion('<SUGGESTION 1>'));
agent.add(new Suggestion('<SUGGESTION 2>'));
```

It seems this is not supported for web-based Dialogflow agents.
How can it be achieved like [this guy](https://miningbusinessdata.com/supportbot/) is doing with his agent?
I want to control the UI from webhook and not by intercepting and updating via frontend code.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the Dialogflow support team. Got a reply that it is currently not supported and I need to write my own UI code to handle this.